# Possible to have listener notified after ServletContext initialization?

Tags: servlets, servlet-listeners

In Servlet 3.0, an application's `ServletContainerInitializer` implementation (if any) is called when the application first BEGINS starting and any `ServletContextListener`s (if any) are called soon after, but still as the context is BEGINNING initialization. Likewise, if you have any `Servlet`s with load-on-startup set, their `init` methods are called as the `Servlet`s are starting up, but still BEFORE the context completes initialization.

In all of these cases, the context has not completed initialization. That is fine and I understand and agree with the reasons for that. What I'm looking for, however, is a way to be notified immediately AFTER the context has completed initialization and is open for business. As an example, it should be possible (not saying I want to do this) for this listener of sorts to perform a web request to the application it resides in. That wouldn't be possible for any of the above mentioned listeners/initializers, since they are called before the application is listening for requests.

Is it possible to do this? Doesn't have to strictly be a Servlet-spec-provided method. Could be Spring Framework or some other library that performs this task.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JBoss Seam](http://www.seamframework.org) they have servlet lifecycle event [**@Initialized**](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/3/3.1.0.Final/reference/en-US/html/servlet-events.html#events.servlet_context_lifecycle_events).

```
public void observeServletContextInitialized(@Observes @Initialized ServletContext ctx) 
{
    System.out.println(ctx.getServletContextName() + " initialized");
}
```